# Macro is running, able to log in but it seems to stall on desired form, no error message

Tags: vba

I'm writing a macro to populate a web form. It is running, it logs in with no problem and goes to the desired page, but at that point, everything stops. The macro continues to run, but the cells are not being populated with information.
This is the full code:

```
    Sub FormFill()

Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://app.pestpac.com/lookup/notificationLocations/default.asp"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy = True
    DoEvents
Loop


'log in
If IE.Document.Title = "PestPac - Login" Then
    IE.Document.getElementById("CompanyKey").Value = "x"
    IE.Document.getElementById("Username").Value = "x"
    IE.Document.getElementById("Password").Value = "x"
    IE.Document.all("butLogin").Click
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop
End If

For i = 2 To 626

    IE.Document.all("butAdd").Click
        If IE.Document.Title = " PestPac - Maintain Notification Locations" Then
            IE.Document.getElementById("Name").Value = Cells(A, i).Value
            IE.Document.getElementById("Address").Value = Cells(B, i).Value
            IE.Document.getElementById("City").Value = Cells(C, i).Value
            IE.Document.getElementById("State").Value = Cells(D, i).Value
            IE.Document.getElementById("Zip").Value = Cells(E, i).Value
            IE.Document.getElementById("Phone").Value = Cells(F, i).Value
            IE.Document.getElementById("Distance").Value = "0.1"

            IE.Document.all("butAdd").Click

        End If

Exit For

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: There can be several reasons why it doesn't work. Most often it's because page doesn't fully load and as result macro doesn't find specified elements. You can add `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))` just before  `For i = 2 To 626` to see if it is the cause, as your `Do While` double condition loop is mostly, but not always enough. If it solves the problem, you can try implementing something like `Y: IE.Document.getElementById("Name").Value = Cells(A, i).Value` and line below `If  IE.Document.getElementById("Name") Is Nothing = True Then GoTo Y` so the macro waits for the element.

Comment: Thank you :) I will try that first thing tomorrow! Hope it works